# Oracle Database Configuration Assistant failed

Tags: oracle, perl, oracle12c, failed-installation, database-installation

In the progress of installing Oracle 12c on CentOS 6.6, there is an error as follows:

```
Error while executing   
"/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/rdbms/admin/dbmssml.sql". Refer to 
"/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/orcl/dbmssml0.log" for more details. Error in 
Process: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/perl/bin/perl
```

I have made the soft link to replace the oracle perl:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/perl $ORACLE_HOME/perl/bin
```

But it still failed. What's wrong?

Comment: Why have you replaced perl? Did you look at the details in the error log, like it told you to?

Comment: Why replace Oracle's perl? Add the contents of that log `/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/orcl/dbmssml0.log` to your question, please.

Comment: Sorry, the problem is hard to describe for me, so here :https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qmpkc8pxi30f87i/AABXpx47XKDUTcPHP08q3PVaa?dl=0

Comment: Is there a dbca-specific log in the cfgtoollogs directory? Or anything relevant in any other logs created there at the time the error occurred?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0ehaih7v4sqxqem/AAAvu2i9DboI3VYO_pC6-ZFDa?dl=0.   These are all files in  **/u01/app/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/orcl** , except the empty files—dbmssml0.log, trace.log.lck and rmanUtil. That's all information i can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check your .bashrc or sth. like that to make sure you've set ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_BASE.

I meet your situation last night,also replace the perl file as you metioned.But doesn't work.

So I do the next:

1. skip the auto dbca and last optional step.
2. dbca to manually create the database.

It works.